# How to loop through a selenium list

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've launched my browser which is headless and I've been able to figure out how to login to the website. However, I can't figure out how to loop through the now close tree to expand it so all the links on the website can be visible for me to grab. Is there any ideas or any code that may help me.

Here is the photo of the closed tree:

[image]

Here is the photo of the open tree:

[image]

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="index__tree" class="index__tree">
<ul class="idx">
<li class="closed"><div class="li"><a href="/doku.php?id=start&amp;idx=all" title="all" class="idx_dir"><strong>all</strong></a> 
</div></li>
<li class="closed"><div class="li"><a href="/doku.php?id=start&amp;idx=architecture" title="architecture" class="idx_dir"> 
<strong>architecture</strong></a></div></li>
```

Comment: Locate the `<a href="...">architecture</a>` element and `.click()` on it.

Comment: Just because the elements aren't _visible_, doesn't mean they aren't present in the html code.  Your sample html doesn't say if there are any more elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Grab all the Elements in the all, architecture. Then use a recursive function until every element is stored in the list. I do not have the exact code but you can do this:

```
1-> parent_A=driver.find_elements_by___your choice___()
2-> parent_B=driver.find_elements_by___your choice___()
3-> Make a list of all the links. all_links=[]
4-> for new_child in parent_A:
      x=new_child.find_elements_by___your choice___().get_attribute('href')
      if x not in all_links:
         all_links.append(x)
         parent_A.append(x)
```

This should give you every link. MAke it effivcient by using if/else loops. It it has helped, let me know.